# Where in Italy was this 1945 picture taken?

Tags: italy, identify-this, photography, florence

Would like to know where this pic was shot from please. Its my dad taken during World War II 1945, in Italy. Thank You.[image]

Comment: That's [Florence](https://www.google.com/search?q=florence+il+duomo&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=StN&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiby-WvpcvTAhUJ0GMKHUBWAScQ_AUICigB&biw=1364&bih=651#safe=off&channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=florence+skyline).

Comment: Sure it is. Here's the almost exact same angle http://www.paradoxplace.com/Perspectives/Italian%20Images/images/Firenze/Firenze_Skylines/900/Florence-Nov07-D4824sAR900.jpg from the greenery and the supposed elevation I would hazard a guess that it's the [Boboli Gardens](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g187895-d191156-i39905804-Boboli_Gardens-Florence_Tuscany.html)

Comment: It is florence and place may be [Basilica of San Miniato al Monte](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Miniato_al_Monte). An [example of view](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=san+miniato+al+monte+florence+view&client=ms-android-samsung&prmd=imvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCgMWAw8vTAhVLsY8KHVGzC-EQ_AUICSgB&biw=360&bih=559#imgrc=tKLad76aBhTXWM:)

Answer (score 17):

As others have correctly identified the location, it is Florence, Firenze, taken from the basilica of San Miniato al Monte which stands atop one of the highest points in the city. You're able to see the River Arno at the base and, soaring above the city, the Cathedral di Santa Maria del Fiore and Il Duomo to the right  and, on the left, the Palazzo Vecchio, the town hall.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It could possibly have been shot from [Piazzale Michangelo](https://www.visitflorence.com/florence-monuments/piazzale-michelangelo.html) , because I was there only few years ago and achieved very similar pic, (without your father of course).

(linked webpage courtesy of Author: Lourdes Flores).

Great spot for viewing the overall city.